# why https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update not work?

Tags: twitter-oauth

I use oauth to access twitter, failed to update when I use https:api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update with user token and secret, but succeed to use https:twitter.com/statuses/update.

Accordding the OAuth Authentication (dev.twitter.com/pages/basic_to_oauth), https:api.twitter.com/1/statuses is suggested, did something I miss? Anybody help me out?

Comment: Got the reason, a stupid mistake. Sorry~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you figured it out in the mean while, but this works for me:
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/...
Perhaps it wasn't active when you tried ?